# How to get selected Data Columns from Datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have string array which contains some column names which may be valid or not.
I have to iterate over DataTable and return columns which are present in it.

Comment: What did you tried so far? You should look to the DataSet.DataTable.Columns..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    static public IEnumerable<DataColumn> GetColumns(DataTable dt)
    {
        var names = new[] { "foo", "bar" };
        return dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Where(c => names.Contains(c.ColumnName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string getcolumns(DataTable dt,string[] array)
    {
        string columns = "";
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            if(array.Contains(column.ColumnName))
            {
            columns += column.ColumnName + ",";

            }
       }
       return columns;
    }
```